# Bash > how to log Bash script efficiently to a predetermined log file

Tags: bash, logging

I have the logging issue on Bash script for pretty long time. Currently in my project, in order to log the standard logging data to a pre-defined text file, our team made use of Java's log4j and slf4j to do the log, say every time when logging information call the implemented java class to log. But isn't this a bit clumsy? calling the Java is way heavy to the system. I am afraid that most of the time of running the Bash script is taken by calling the Java logging. I also wish someone can comment on this solution :)

I also read about the Linux's intrinsic syslog. It looks cool, but the redirection of the syslog is difficult to control.

I  is there any bettery solution for this?

Comment: If you're booting a new JVM each time you need to write a piece of log, yes, you are spending way too much time logging things. If you just boot the JVM once and then echo logs to its stdin, then you're probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data should be logged?

Normally, you can log all sorts of things with the "echo" command. I mean, this is done nearly everywhere and is one of the normal standard techniques without using java, as long as you would not use "logger" to write to the syslog.

Or do it with "logger" (then you have to sort the messages out):

```
#!/bin/bash
logger "test mit logger!"
```

In /var/log/messages:
2016-04-12T10:58:11.785979+02:00 as501755 coliban: test mit logger!

or did i misunderstood you?

regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using the logger of syslog, but that only goes to /var/log/messages other than the file, which is pre-determined. I also would like to get the comment of using Java log4j and slf4j